# How to reorder CSS Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex container with flex-direction: row and n items, they do not have fixed height or width. On desktop I am showing 2 columns with an exact order. On mobile it is one column but the order is not what I want. Basically I want to show the items from the second column after the items from the first column . How to reorder them to achieve the desired result? Here is an example.

On Desktop two columns

```
item1   item2
item3   item4
item5   item6
```

Desired result with one column

```
item1
item3
item5
item2
item4
item6
```

Here is a html and css

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 520px) {
  .item {
    flex: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">item1</div>
  <div class="item">item2</div>
  <div class="item">item3</div>
  <div class="item">item4</div>
  <div class="item">item5</div>
  <div class="item">item6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant css, please?

Comment: @MaikLowrey it is nothing fancy, I added the HTML and CSS to the question

Comment: Why don't you put the two columns inside a parent flex container and just give flex wrap to the parent? Because in your first column already the items are in order 1,3,5. So once the second column will wrap you will have desired result.

Or do you want to have class with every item etc and then handle the order property?

Comment: @WahabShah Your idea is good. you can show that as a different answer:)

Comment: @WahabShah in terms of building the HTMl in loop it is not practical

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this

```
  .item:nth-child(2n - 1) {
    order: -1;
  }
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 520px) {
  .item {
    flex: 100%;
  }

  .item:nth-child(2n - 1) {
    order: -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">item1</div>
  <div class="item">item2</div>
  <div class="item">item3</div>
  <div class="item">item4</div>
  <div class="item">item5</div>
  <div class="item">item6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. `n` how is it calculated? Is it possible to more explain? because it become `nth-child(-1)` - `nth-child(1)` - `nth-child(3)` - `nth-child(5)` - `nth-child(7)` and .... !

Comment: `2n - 1` represents all the odd numbers.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `flex` and `order` for that:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  width: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .item {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .item3 {
    order: 2;
  }
  .item5 {
    order: 3;
  }
  .item2 {
    order: 4;
  }
  .item4 {
    order: 5;
  }
  .item6 {
    order: 6;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item1">item1</div>
  <div class="item item2">item2</div>
  <div class="item item3">item3</div>
  <div class="item item4">item4</div>
  <div class="item item5">item5</div>
  <div class="item item6">item6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very good! 1up!

Comment: the items are n they are not fixed to 6 items so it will not work

Comment: @VladimirGatev check out my answer. it's flexible.

Comment: @doğukan this is what I was looking for, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `order` property with flexbox. Here is the resource => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

```css
@media (max-width: 520px) {
  .item:nth-child(1) {
     order: 1;
  }
  
  .item:nth-child(2) {
     order: 4;
  }

  .item:nth-child(3) {
     order: 2;
  }

  .item:nth-child(4) {
     order: 5;
  }

  .item:nth-child(5) {
     order: 3;
  }

  .item:nth-child(6) {
     order: 6;
  }
}
```